# PowerShell/EWS Send message with Delayed/Deferred delivery

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I have a function that sends an email (EDIT1: from an ON-PREM mailbox) using delayed delivery, via COM objects. I am trying to write an equivalent function for EWS. I got a working PoC but it has 1 glaring issue: The message sits in the sent items folder, not the outbox, until the defer date arrives, then it sends as expected.

I'm using the SendAndSaveCopy method and I tried specifying the Outbox folder. This did put the message into the Outbox, but when it sends, it doesn't get moved to the Sent Items folder.

```
$service = New-EwsService # .... assume this works; My RequestedServerVersion is Exchange2013

$EmailMessage = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage -ArgumentList $service 
$EmailMessage.Subject = 'outbox test'
$EmailMessage.Body = 'this is a test'
$EmailMessage.ToRecipients.Add('someone@somewhere.com')
$SendOn = (get-date).AddMinutes(5)
    $defer = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
        0x3FEF, # 'PR_DEFERRED_SEND_TIME',
        [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::SystemTime
    )
$EmailMessage.SetExtendedProperty($defer,$SendOn.ToUniversalTime())

# $EmailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Outbox)  
$EmailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy()
```

Another thing I noticed was that if I open the message in Outlook while it's waiting to send, and I look at the delay delivery settings, it's not configured (in the Outlook UI). And if I hit send on that item, it immediately sends. I would assume that the config would be in the message and visible from the UI. (The expected behavior is the message in the Outbox list should be in italics until you open it, then it will return to italics if you hit send, otherwise it won't be italic and won't send when the defer time arrives).

Is there anyone who knows why the folder behavior doesn't match the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/jj220496(v=exchg.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

> The message.SendAndSaveCopy() line results in a call to the service. If the call is successful, the email message will be available in the caller’s Outbox folder. After the email message is sent, a copy of the message will be created in the Sent Items folder.

EDIT2: I ended up going with an alternative solution. Instead of queuing messages in the mailbox directly, I am exporting the `Send-MailMessage` parameter hash to XML, then using the Task Scheduler to execute at a later time, grabbing that object from cache and splatting it on the function call. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

The docs you refer to are very old and the behaviour has changed.  In Office 365, the deferred message is saved in Drafts folder until the time of sending, at which point it is sent and then saved to Sent Items.

Note that Outlook Object Model works against Outlook, while EWS works directly with the mailbox on Exchange.

Comment: Hi David, The mailbox in question is on-prem, not in O365. The behavior you describe also doesn't match what I saw. Now that you mention the doc's age, I noticed that it's also for v2010. I will look for the correct doc version for our env and circle back. Thanks.